# discord.py send prefix when mentioned

Tags: python, discord.py

My bot send a the message always when someone mention him, but i want to bot respond only when them message contents has only a mention.
Exemple, when i send *@bot a* he sends to me the await message, and i want to remove this and make the bot send the await message only when someone send *@bot*

```
   if message.content.startswith('<@868346872438345738>') or message.content.startswith('<@!868346872438345738>'):
        await message.reply(f'Olá {message.author.name}, o meu prefixo é {bot.user.mention} ou {altprefix}! para mais ajuda use {altprefix}help', mention_author=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using startswith(), that ignores all the characters after the specified sequence.

You can convert message.content into a string and perform every check you need.

Something like this:

```
 if message.content.startswith('<@868346872438345738>') or message.content.startswith('<@!868346872438345738>'):
      if str(message.content) == "@bot":
           await message.reply(f'Olá {message.author.name}, o meu prefixo é {bot.user.mention} ou {altprefix}! para mais ajuda use {altprefix}help', mention_author=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

this code worked for me

```
if str(ctx.content) == f"<@{self.bot.user.id}>" or str(ctx.content) == f"<@!{self.bot.user.id}>":
```